# Fake data to preview custom view

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-view, android-custom-view

I'm writing custom view for charts. How does I can to pass fake data into view, when it is in edit mode? (I know about `isInEditMode`, but when I'm trying to pass data inside `init` block it crash preview)

That will be without any code in init (and you can look at setItems code)
[image]

And screenshot when i'm adding `setItems inside` init`
[image]

But it still works when app running [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio layout editor cannot render custom views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592965/android-studio-layout-editor-cannot-render-custom-views)

Comment: The preview panel should also be showing you an error explaining why the rendering failed. It might be because of certain resources that are not supported in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out the problem. (Thanks @Subhrajyoti Sen)
I've looked at errors with render and that's shown me that method setItems is not found (quite strange).
i've written next code

```kotlin
   init {
        if(isInEditMode) {
            valuesDiff = 12
            minValue = 3
            chartItems.addAll(listOf(10, 15, 3, 14, 12, 5))
        }
    }
```

And that solved the problem